# return file_get_contents Array in Such way that Array_sum, Min, Max, Count will work?

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.airbnb.com/s/Prague~Prague-1--Czech-Republic?source=bb');
$regex = '/<span class=\"h3 price-amount\">(.*)span>/';
preg_match_all($regex,$data,$match);

echo 'TOTAL: ' . array_sum($match[1]); //Incorrect
echo 'Minimum: ' . min($match[1]); //Incorrect
echo 'Maximum: ' . max($match[1]); //Incorrect
echo 'Average: ' . array_sum($match[1]) / count($match[1]); //Incorrect
echo 'Number of properties: ' .  count($match[1]); //OK
```

`var_dump($match[1]);` results:

```
array(18) { 
    [0]=> string(4) "58 
        string(4) "42 
        string(5) "103 
        string(4) "52 
        string(4) "46 
        string(5) "109 
        string(4) "89 
        string(4) "55 
        string(4) "95 
        string(5) "110 
        string(5) "345 
        string(4) "76 
        string(4) "45 
        string(4) "76 
        string(5) "101 
        string(4) "83 
        string(4) "77 
        string(4) "58
```

`var_dump($match[0]);` results(I have tried [0] also for array_sum but it's always 0:

```
array(18) { 
    [0]=> string(39) "62" 
    [1]=> string(39) "42" 
    [2]=> string(39) "52" 
    [3]=> string(39) "54" 
    [4]=> string(39) "58" 
    [5]=> string(39) "46" 
    [6]=> string(39) "89" 
    [7]=> string(40) "122" 
    [8]=> string(40) "103"
    [9]=> string(39) "55" 
    [10]=> string(39) "76" 
    [11]=> string(39) "69" 
    [12]=> string(39) "90" 
    [13]=> string(40) "110" 
    [14]=> string(39) "24" 
    [15]=> string(39) "38" 
    [16]=> string(39) "50" 
    [17]=> string(39) "23" 
}
```

Why I can't figure out what's wrong it seems to me that the array return string numbers from regex match but the array calculation isn't working.

```
print_r($match[0]);

Array ( 
    [0] => 46 
    [1] => 58 
    [2] => 103 
    [3] => 42 
    [4] => 52 
    [5] => 62 
    [6] => 38 
    [7] => 60 
    [8] => 77 
    [9] => 76 
    [10] => 69 
    [11] => 54 
    [12] => 89 
    [13] => 130 
    [14] => 50 
    [15] => 76 
    [16] => 167 
    [17] => 110 
)
```

Comment: I tried your code, and this won't work, because you have wrong values in your array: `11387</`

Comment: @lolka_bolka Hmm how you found this out? Yes regex looks like is missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `$regex = '/<span class=\"h3 price-amount\">(.*)<\/span>/';`

You had a missing `<\/` at your closing span.

And add this line, before min/max, etc... `$match[1] = array_map('intval', $match[1]);`

Output is:

```
 TOTAL: 290500
 Minimum: 5820
 Maximum: 29860
 Average: 16138.888888889
 Number of properties: 18
```

NOTE: Do you realized, this page is returning different values every time you run the script?

Comment: yep I saw this after your comment but I'm interested in how you debugged it? Thanks! will accept your answer when possible.

Comment: just `var_dump($match);` and check the array of key 1.

Comment: I am using xdebug, what is makes more readable the `var_dump()`

Comment: what is the array_map intval does in this case? about the different values (Different properties on website every visit)

Comment: Nothing about different properties. array map just convert the strings to integers in the array.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, when dealing with this task you can also use an HTML Parser DOMDocument in particular with xpath.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
// load the page
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.airbnb.com/s/Prague~Prague-1--Czech-Republic?source=bb');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$prices = array();
// get all span with that class
$elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="h3 price-amount"]');
foreach($elements as $e) { // get all the values and push it inside the array
    $prices[] = intval(trim($e->nodeValue));
}

$total = array_sum($prices); // then array sum them
echo $total;
```